# type or namespace Task could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio express for windows phone, 
when i use TASK in my app, i get the above mentioned error,
even System.Threading.Tasks is also not found.
What could be my problem??

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Threading` to your project?

Comment: it is not found in my reference manger also.

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: Are you using Async in wp7? if so, have you referenced http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to target at least .NET Framework 4 in your project. You can change this under project properties.

Also, changing the target will not add the reference for the library, so you have to do this manually after changing the target framework.

Answer (score 32):

Right click on Task, choose Resolve > System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used: using System.Threading.Tasks; in Dotnet core project.